# Puppeteer.js - Scraping private fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have built my web scraper on Puppeteer.js to enter flats ads and scrape certain informations about it. Suddenly it stopped working - every field was a **null**.
The way I used to retrieve it was `await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, await page.$(selector))`

I decided to manually enter a page my bot visits and after checking a selector path, it returned
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Private field '#root' must be declared in an enclosing class` and this probably is the cause why I get **nulls**.

*[example link](https://www.olx.pl/d/oferta/2-pokojowe-mieszkanierozkladowewindaul-krucza-bezposrednio-CID3-IDL9yQN.html#3222b9c8bc;promoted)*
and price selector `#root > div.css-50cyfj > div.css-1on7yx1 > div:nth-child(3) > div.css-n9feq4 > div.css-1wws9er > div.css-dcwlyx > h3`

Is this possible to make Puppeteer retrieve information from given selector if I can't get it manually?
Is there any workaround for it?
Or is it some way of securing data to prevent web scrapers?

Comment: Interesting... can you show how you assign the selector in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no private fields in HTML really. You seem to be having some misconfiguration in the code. To fix this quickly, you don't really need `#root` selector to pick the price on the target site, the rest without it, is good and precise enough:

```
const selector = 'div.css-50cyfj > div.css-1on7yx1 > div:nth-child(3) > div.css-n9feq4 > div.css-1wws9er > div.css-dcwlyx > h3';
```